# What does that mean "$vm1 | Set-AzureSubnet"?

Tags: powershell, variables, command

You can see my question but I don't ask about the variable and the command but about the "|". I know that I can use it to execute first the command on the left of "|" and then execute the command on the right. But I don't have any idea what does it mean with the variable(which is defined already) on the left and the command of the right.

```
$vm1 | Set-AzureSubnet -SubnetNames "defualt"
```

Why do I ask? If I understood it I can fix an error, hopefully.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `|` symbol is PowerShell's '[pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6)' - it allows you to take the output of one command and send it as input to another.  In this case the contents of variable `$vm1` are passed as input to the cmdlet `Set-AzureSubnet`, which uses the value to do its job.  Not all cmdlets accept input like this - check the individual cmdlet help for details.